# How can i write unit test for code that connected a device

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I write a program that connected a device.

For example I want test `reset` method that send reset request(it is not HTTP request it can be socket) for the device.(device can be anything).
I don't want test the request just want ensure that method work correctly.

> In computer programming, unit testing is a method by which individual
>   units of source code, sets of one or more computer program modules
>   together with associated control data, usage procedures, and operating
>   procedures, are tested to determine if they are fit for use.[1]
>   Intuitively, one can view a unit as the smallest testable part of an
>   application. In procedural programming a unit could be an entire
>   module but is more commonly an individual function or procedure. In
>   object-oriented programming a unit is often an entire interface, such
>   as a class, but could be an individual method.

I can not test the `reset` method independently(without the device).
Can I write  unit test for `reset` method?
How can i write unit test for these situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mock library, for example: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks . Then, in the unit test you can create a mock that implements the device's interface, and you can verify that a particular method (in this case - reset) was called.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a device emulation system, assuming the device is important to you and you really need to know if your code works with it.

A "mock" only creates an interface, while your protocol needs to be tested. For instance, a `reset` method takes a non-zero amount of time for the device to physically and logically reset. A mock won't cut it. Similarly, a device can only accept some commands while in certain states; it is often essential that you have a state machine backing your emulator.

You don't need to implement your device emulator in C#; you just need to interface to the device emulator. For instance, there are highly-customizable simulation systems that implement state machines and can be driven by test data files or scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by "protocol"? In this case, the methods of the device interface being called with appropriate arguments form a protocol (a way of communicating with the device). So as long as you want to test the protocol in the understanding I've mentioned a mock validating method calls is exactly what you need.

Comment: Protocols involving devices are value, state and time based. Mock libraries test none of those things. The device emulation needs to produce good values, bad values and good-looking but inappropriate values to see that the software under test can handle them. The emulation also needs to respond in a timely manner, and also in untimely manners -- what happens if the power goes off on the device during the reset? -- does the test pass or fail? Or recover correctly? Similar statements apply to states of the device.

Comment: You are right, that these are all important things. But, to test the software against bad, odd and other values you don't need to emulate the device - just input these values to the created mock to be received by the software. What are you talking about is integration testing, or black-box testing. In unit-testing you must be sure that you are testing only one thing. Writing emulation software is another place for additional mistakes. That's why, first of all you need a good set of UNIT tests.

Comment: For unit testing, you need test only the value part of the protocols. However, unit testing is the least interesting part of testing, although unit testing is essential for long term maintenance of software. Testing of state machines and timing dependencies is where the vast majority of your bugs will be caught.

Comment: 1) What's your source of information that unit testing is only about value? Wiki definition doesn't mention anything about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing . AFAIK you can, and should test activity with unit tests.


2) Sorry, but your feeling about what's interesting and what is not is irrelevant here. The author's question IS about unit testing.

Comment: 1) No source - Only in the broadest definition of "unit" is a device driver one. Obviously there are levels or a scale from unit testing (only leaf nodes) through integration testing (system as a whole) -- device drivers are well above the leaf testing scale. 2) People throw around the word "unit testing" as if that is what they want. I focused on what he wanted rather than the words "unit testing".

Comment: And the device driver can and should be tested without the device! I don't understand why do you claim that device drivers are above the scale of unit testing. Don't drivers have methods/functions? Don't they have classes? Shouldn't their implementation have a good decoupled architecture? All this justifies unit testing, by the definition.